# image background like a frame using android drawable xml

Tags: android, xml, image, background, drawable

I need to create an imageview with background drawable like a frame but not getting the required design.

I'm getting these images

[image: image with centercrop scaletype]

[image: iimage with centerfit]

But the required designs are

[image]

Comment: add relevant code.. and if you are setting bordered frame as background, the image will be overlapped on it..

Comment: @Jaspal: May be you should have rounded corner image that shown download by API call

Answer (score 0):

In your layout, set the background to the required colour.

```
android:background="#FFF9C4"
```

Then add the ImageView inside the layout and add padding on Left, Right, Top and Bottom of size as per requirement.

You can explore shape too, using shape you can control the corners as well.